# access state data from store into a string vue.js

Tags: string, vue.js, axios, vuex

Hey guys so I am trying to add state data from my store into a string in one of my axios calls within actions. Here is my store:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store
({
  state: {
    participants: [],
    filterTags: ["foo", "swag"],
    page: 1,
    perPage: 2,
    filterTagName: "",
   }
}
```

Here is my action call:

```
 actions: {
async loadParticipants ({commit}) {
  try {
    console.log(this.state.page);
    await axios
  .get('/dash/participant?perPage=2&page=1&string=f')

      .then(r => r.data)
      .then(participants => {
        console.log(participants.docs);
        console.log("Hit me");
        commit('setParticipants', participants)
      })
  }
  catch (e) {
    if (e.response)
      console.log(e.response);
    throw e
  }
}
```

I want to add the store's state data where it says { INSERT DATA HERE } within the axios call:

```
 .get('/dash/participant?perPage={INSERT DATA HERE }&page={ INSERT DATA HERE }&string=f')
```

Any input appreciated thank you!

Comment: Does this need retagging as vuejs2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action, you have access to the whole store, so instead to just getting only the commit declaring the param as `({commit})`, you can add the state too:

`async loadParticipants ({commit, state}) {`

So you can use the `state` variable in your method body:

```
actions: {
  async loadParticipants ({commit, state}) {
    try {
      console.log(this.state.page);
      await axios
    .get(`/dash/participant?perPage=${state.perPage}&page=${state.page}&string=${state.filterTagName}`)

        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(participants => {
          console.log(participants.docs);
          console.log("Hit me");
          commit('setParticipants', participants)
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
      if (e.response)
        console.log(e.response);
      throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to fill your query params with the values from your vuex store?
Just pass the `state` into your action. And then you can add the state to your query params with a little help of template iterals. `${some-js-variable}`

You can also directly destruct the response and grab the data. 
Not sure why you make promise like `then()` statements if you use `async` and `await`.

```
actions: {
 async loadParticipants ({commit, state}) {
  try {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/dash/participant?perPage=${state.perPage}&page=${state.page}&string=f`)
    console.log(data)

  }
  catch (e) {
    if (e.response)
      console.log(e.response);
    throw e
  }
}
```